# could I loop through 3 arrays and join them to one list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, tuples

could I loop through 3 arrays and join to one list ?

```
list1 = ['test1','test2','test3']
list2 = ['2022-12-12T16:44','2022-12-12T13:45','2022-12-12T22:57']
list3 = ['low','medium','high']


can i get something like this? 

result =[
   ['test1','2022-12-12T16:44','low']]
   ['test2','2022-12-12T13:45','medium']
   ['test3','2022-12-12T22:57','high']
]
```

Answer (score 3):

`zip` allows you to iterate simultaneously on several iterables (truncating to the length of the shortest iterable):

```
list4 = [ [a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(list1,list2,list3)]

# [['test1', '2022-12-12T16:44', 'low'],
#  ['test2', '2022-12-12T13:45', 'medium'],
#  ['test3', '2022-12-12T22:57', 'high']]
```

Comment: It's prob. worthy to mention if - if one or more lists are not the *same* size, then zip_longest could help that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHao, just tested `zip_longest` (that I didn't know before); and I fixed my comment on `zip` that was inaccurate.